# Sorting grid items vertically not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

My layout looks like:

```
1 2 3
4 5
```

But I need my layout to look like:

```
1 3 5
2 4
```

Of course, number of items is not fixed, so it can have *n* list items.

When I set `grid-auto-flow: column;` my grid stops working and all items are in same row.

How can I fix that?

```css
.link-list-grid {
  display: grid;
  gap: 10px;
}

.link-list-grid-1 {
  grid-template-columns: repeat(1, 1fr);
}

.link-list-grid-2 {
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
}

.link-list-grid-3 {
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
}

.standardTextImage .content ul.linklist li a {
  color: #08107B;
}

.standardTextImage .content ul.linklist li a:hover {
  color: #0787c5;
}

.standardTextImage .content ul.linklist li a:hover i {
  color: #0787c5;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .link-list-grid {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(1, 1fr);
  }
}
```

```html
<ul data-number-columns="3" class="linklist link-list-grid link-list-grid-3">
  <li>
    <a href="http://google.com" title="" target="_blank">1<i class="icon icon-angle-right"></i></a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="http://google.de" title="" target="_blank">2<i class="icon icon-angle-right"></i></a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="http://google.com" title="" target="_blank">3<i class="icon icon-angle-right"></i></a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="http://google.com" title="" target="_blank">4<i class="icon icon-angle-right"></i></a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="http://examplecom.de" title="" target="_blank">5<i class="icon icon-angle-right"></i></a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Please revise the demo above so it shows the problem. The output doesn't match your sketch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly you need `grid-auto-flow: column` and then limit the height (or specify a number of rows) to get wrapping.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  min-width: 0;
  min-height: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

ul {
  display: inline-grid;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(2, auto);
  /*  sets number of rows */
  list-style: none;
}

li {
  padding: .5em;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  margin: .25em;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
  <li>Item 4</li>
  <li>Item 5</li>
  <li>Item 6</li>
</ul>
```